# Can I create a custom field in a report

Tags: reporting, custom-field

I have a report on events which includes three checkbox (Boolean) fields: Attended, Canceled, Waiting List. I would love to either create a custom field for just the report or a bucket field with values such as "Attended", "Did not cancel or attend", "Canceled". Currently I have the three fields as groups on a summary report, but "Attended: []" is not as user friendly as I want.
I suspect that I may have use VisualForce or Apex. If that's the case please be detailed as I've only been using Salesforce for two months and with no formal training.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a custom field in a report. Fields are created at the object level only. As you've noted you can indeed create "Buckets" which might be one way of displaying the desired results without adding an additional field to your object, however as Mike has pointed out below, only picklist, text and numeric fields can be bucketed which won't solve your issue.

Comment: You can't bucket checkboxes; only picklist, text, and numeric fields - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_bucketing_adding.htm&language=en. Unless you meant a custom field that did the bucketing?

Comment: I would love to bucket from the multiple checkbox fields, but I don't think that's on option. Looks like creating an object (maybe "Result") on the event using a formula with if or case. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Good catch Mike. Thanks for adding the clarification on what can be bucketed. I was primarily attempting to answer the creating fields portion of the question without considering whether or not checkboxes could be bucketed.

Comment: @SCARon, did you ever figure out a workable solution?

Comment: @JustAGirlyGeek, unfortunately no. I could have made a formula field, but since this was just for a one-time report, that seemed a bit excessive.